# register Web API controller from class library

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel

I have a .NET Core worker project and want to add a library providing several HTTP endpoints. **I have to stay with the worker project, I can't change it to a Web API project.** What I have done so far:

- I created a worker project
- I created a library project
- I added a reference to the library in the worker project
- In the **Worker.csproj** and **Lib.csproj** I added `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` to the item group to gain access to the webbuilder stuff
- I installed the package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core** in the library project
- In the library project I add several extensions classes and a web API controller for testing purposes

.

```
public static class IApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder AddLibrary(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        applicationBuilder.UseRouting();
        applicationBuilder.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        return applicationBuilder;
    }
}

public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddLibrary(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(); // this might be not needed
        services.AddControllers();
        return services;
    }
}

public static class KestrelServerOptionsExtensions
{
    public static void AddLibrary(this KestrelServerOptions kestrelServerOptions)
    {
        kestrelServerOptions.ListenLocalhost(5000); // value from config
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

- In the worker project I created a `Startup` class

.

```
internal class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLibrary();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        applicationBuilder.AddLibrary();
    }
}
```

- In the worker project I modified the `Program` class to

.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
            {
                webHostBuilder.UseKestrel(kestrelServerOptions =>
                {
                    kestrelServerOptions.AddLibrary();
                }).UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

- I run the project and call *GET http://localhost:5000/users*
- I would expect a 200 but get a 404 and the debugger does not hit the controller endpoint in the library project

Does someone know what I'm missing?

It is possible for me to [Add Web API controller endpoint to Kestrel worker project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154868/add-web-api-controller-endpoint-to-kestrel-worker-project) but it is not possible for me to add web controllers to a library project and call them from the library.

Comment: Hmm I did the same and I can reproduce his problem ...

Comment: I am able to reproduce this problem, in the logs I can see that no routes are found for /Users, but I can't figure out why.
You can make it work by changing your worker project to a web project, by using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web instead of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker. The worker service will run the same way with this Sdk.
This doesn't answer your question but it's a workaround.

Comment: yeah thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it's not possible for me to change it to a Web API project

Comment: try changing `[Route("[controller]")]` to `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]`. I hope this would resolve the error.
Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a working solution on my computer.

#### Solving the problem

It turns out it's actually really simple. MVC loads [`ApplicationPart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.applicationpart?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2)s from different assemblies. In a normal web application setup, this seems to be picked up properly, even when using Razor Class Libraries. However, when using a worker service and either a library, or a Razor Class Library, it doesn't work, and so the route for your controller isn't registered.

To add the library as an application part, open up the `IServiceCollectionExtensions` class you created, and change it to this:

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddLibrary(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddControllers()
            // Notice the assembly is the type of this class, as this
            // is the assembly the controller is in.
            // You'll have to call this for every assembly you have
            // controllers in, except for any controllers
            // you might put in your worker service project.
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(IServiceCollectionExtensions).Assembly);

        return services;
    }
}
```

Now, starting the app and sending a request to `http://localhost:5000/users` will work. I've confirmed this works for both libraries and Razor Class Libraries.

[image: worker service routing]

I should also say that controllers in the worker service project itself will work as normal - there is no special setup required for those.

#### Things you don't need

1. You don't need the call to `services.AddMvc()` in `IServiceCollectionExtensions`. Calling this, without parameters, is the [same as calling `AddControllersWithViews()` and `AddRazorPages()`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c029cdf7caa9a4f722a3056dc079979fc248cedb/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27).
2. You don't need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` package in your library project - mine runs fine just with the framework reference you added. The only package I have in there is for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core`.

Comment: hey, thanks for your solution! adding this `.AddApplicationPart(typeof(IServiceCollectionExtensions).Assembly);` solved the problem.

Comment: But there is one question left: `kestrelServerOptions.ListenLocalhost(myValueFromConfig);` by doing so the server starts to listen for two ports ... 5000 and my config value ... I made a screenshot from the console https://i.imgur.com/AvhcUDh.png

Comment: so the listener works fine for my configured port but why does it listen to the port 5000 too?

Comment: @OlafSvenson No problem. Kestrel is only listening to one port for me. I just tried calling `kestrelServerOptions.ListenLocalhost(n)` with two different numbers, and it does bind to two different ports. So have you accidentally called it twice? (Maybe once from the library, and once in your worker's `Program`?)

Comment: ah exactly, sorry my bad!

Comment: @OlafSvenson No problem! :)

Comment: Additional reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-5.0